# How to find duplicate images and compare their meta-data?

Tags: windows, software-rec, deduplication

Is there an application for Windows that finds duplicate images and lets quickly preview the image and, what is most important, the meta-data of the image files.

I can see there are programs for finding files with equal content, only the name being different, and there are others that let you find files with similar images ignoring the meta-data.

However, when I am presented with two files that contain the same image, the most important difference becomes exactly the meta data. For example, there are some tags or description for one image, but there are none (or different) for the other.

And the programs I've found offer only the image preview, and compare the file name, path, size, but not the meta data.

Comment: Where would that metadata be created/edited? I don't remember seeing tags or descriptions on images in Windows before.

Comment: Well, one place you can edit some image meta data is in the file properties window: I can add author, title, keywords there. I can use other programs, like Picasa, to add caption and keywords. And I've seen there is a difference of how different programs may add the keywords, so, I suppose, there is no one common standard. I've read about EXIF and IPTC metadata, maybe there are more or any application may use their own format. I would like to see all the meta-data there is in plain/raw mode - that would be the best.

Comment: The issue is not only that different programs use different formats for metadata, they'll also use different storage locations. A deduplication application that would want to respect that data, would have to be able to read all the different storage locations and formats. While that's not impossible, it would certainly be hard to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that risk I would be deliberately taking on me, that's not a problem. The application should be able to compare just what's in the file itself. I do not want the application to respect the meta-data while it's comparing the files. I just want it to be able to read and show me the meta-data when it's displaying the found duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using TotalCommander http://ghisler.com/index.htm (free or low-price) for years. It comes with search-for-duplicates functionality.

When duplicate images are listed in virtual directory or copied to physical one, you can use IrfanView http://www.irfanview.com (free) to look into the EXIF tags of photos.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, this is not too easy to do for quick de-duplication of a lot of files. I have found a few programs that finds duplicates, and a few files that display meta data, but there is none that would do both.

BTW, where do you get the free Total Commander version? On the page you gave, it's written it's "shareware".

Comment: Yes, doing both tool not seen yet.
Would need some programming like using python and EXIF lib--hints welcome if you find such a project.     free-/shareware: just try, it *is* free for ever and fully functional, just annoys a bit by requesting to press 1, 2 or 3 at start; but for professional use much better than MS explorer---my employers always bought it, much more productive every day.